# Verbose mode to debug the google cloud connectivity from java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, verbose

I want to connect to google cloud storage bucket from java or any other way and want to capture the route taken from source to destination and debug where the packets are getting blocked .

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `traceroute storage.googleapis.com` in the terminal.

storage.googleapis.com is the main domain for all the service endpoints for storage.